# Ограничения на частоту запросов

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Частотные ограничение действуют для каждого пользователя(токена пользователя) или приложения в целом?

Я хотел бы сделать авторизацию через ВК на сайте, но если ограничение составляет 3 запроса в секунду от приложения, то если 4 человека попытаются зарегистрироваться в один момент - выдаст ошибку. Если же ограничение касается пользователя(токена), то это значит от одного пользователя не может быть больше 3 запросов в секунду, чего более чем достаточно.

Пример: у меня есть 100 токенов доступа от 100 пользователей и это значит, что в секунду я могу сделать 300 запросов при условии, что от каждого пользователя будет не более 3 запросов.

Comment: На приложение. Копипаста с документации. Ну логично же. Максимальное число обращений к сервисным (https://vk.com/dev/secure) методам зависит от числа пользователей, установивших приложение. Если приложение установило меньше 10 000 человек, то можно совершать 5 запросов в секунду, до 100 000 — 8 запросов, до 1 000 000 — 20 запросов, больше 1 млн. — 35 запросов в секунду.

Comment: Ну это логично и для токена. Если много токенов, то количество запросов от 1 токена возрастает. Просто встречаю противоречивую информацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ поддержки:
Здравствуйте, Сс!

Ограничения распространяются на пользователей, а не приложение. У вас может быть и миллион пользователей онлайн, это никак не будет мешать делу. Так что ваш пример верен.

Теплой и солнечной осени!
Команда поддержки ВКонтакте